# Ubuntu GNOME 16.04: System becomes Unrecoverable after locking the screen

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, gnome, freeze, lock-screen

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with Kernel version 4.7.10-040710 with NVidia Ge Force 940MX GPU. 
 This problem comes whenever i keep my laptop busy for some program (such as some Machine Learning Model or GPU intensive Deep Learning Model) which takes between 2-24 hours to train.

If I try to lock the screen amidst code running or after code running, the system enters into some unrecoverable state, wherein no combination of keys or actions effect the black out screen. I can't even switch to TTY terminal to check the corresponding problem.

[Here](http://www.writeurl.com/text/z1yvgdmzrsiu78i13o0w/x1s1amq2s4cysjixmj4m/) is link to the Part of syslog file near such a failure. I don't know how to understand the syslog, else i would have copied the exact part here.

Any help/advice appreciated.

Comment: Same problem withUbuntu Unity 16.04 + GeoForce 960.